# If $y=3\tan^3{\frac{x}{2}}$ and $y'=a\sin{bx} \cos{cx} $

Tags: trigonometry, differential

I want to solve the following problem. 
If $y=3\tan^3{\frac{x}{2}}$ and $y'=a\sin{bx} \cos{cx} $, then $\frac{a} {bc} =$

What I have done so far, $y'=\frac{9}{2} \tan^2{ \frac{x}{2}} \sec^2{\frac{x}{2} }$

But I don't know, how change that to $sin$ and $cos$ term
[image]

Comment: Are you sure the question is as stated? $y'$ has no upper bound, but $a \sin bx \cos cx$ surely has.

Comment: Yes, I am. The "original" question was in bahasa Indonesia. I can't show you the picture of my book, I can't upload a picture from my phone.

Comment: You can always put the link in and someone will embed it into the post for you. If you have the answer, that would be great as well.

Comment: I already added the photo.

Comment: If the question is really as stated, you probably have a mistake in the question, or some mistake in the solution that makes an answer possible. I suggest you move on from this question as there are often lots of mistakes in textbooks.

Answer (score 0):

I have get
$$y'=9\, \left( \tan \left( x/2 \right)  \right) ^{2} \left( 1/2+1/2\,
 \left( \tan \left( x/2 \right)  \right) ^{2} \right) 
$$
this simplifies to
$$y'={\frac {9-9\,\cos \left( x \right) }{ \left( \cos \left( x \right) +1
 \right) ^{2}}}
$$ multiplying denominator and numerator by $$1+\cos(x)$$
we get
$$\frac{9\sin^2(x)}{(1+\cos(x))^3}$$

Comment: I also get that. But, I can't convert to the desired form.